# how to change `TRUE` and `FALSE` labels in ggplot2 generated by geo_col?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom, geom-col

the data: `dput(gsea)`

```
    structure(list(ID = c("ab1", "ab2", "ab3", "ab4", "ab5", "ab6", 
"ab7", "ab8", "ab9", "ab10", "ab11", "ab12", "ab13", "ab14", 
"ab15", "ab16", "ab17", "ab18", "ab19", "ab20"), Count = c(183L, 
37L, 15L, 30L, 38L, 98L, 49L, 58L, 43L, 49L, 98L, 10L, 15L, 83L, 
14L, 5L, 129L, 69L, 32L, 19L), NES = c(3.115511918, 2.65379757, 
2.385595991, 2.310872715, 2.166809058, 2.157225827, 2.112706611, 
-1.982794655, -1.96510639, -1.890716501, -1.845158581, 1.843252451, 
-1.833650877, -1.832752633, 1.830915101, 1.827824231, -1.804884734, 
-1.79943276, -1.786694788, -1.779892361), pvalue = c(1.4e-43, 
6.72e-12, 3.55e-07, 6.6e-08, 8.33e-07, 8.16e-14, 1.31e-08, 1.01e-06, 
7.33e-06, 5.55e-05, 8.32e-06, 0.002090754, 0.0008865, 1.06e-06, 
0.003576374, 0.005822333, 7.09e-08, 3.15e-05, 0.000196647, 0.001113372
), REG = c("up", "up", "up", "up", "up", "up", "up", "down", 
"down", "down", "down", "up", "down", "down", "up", "up", "down", 
"down", "down", "down"), ABS = c(3.115511918, 2.65379757, 2.385595991, 
2.310872715, 2.166809058, 2.157225827, 2.112706611, 1.982794655, 
1.96510639, 1.890716501, 1.845158581, 1.843252451, 1.833650877, 
1.832752633, 1.830915101, 1.827824231, 1.804884734, 1.79943276, 
1.786694788, 1.779892361)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

I tried to plot using the following code:

```
ggplot(gsea, aes(reorder(ID, NES), NES)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill=NES<0)) + 
scale_color_manual(name = 'NES', labels = c("Suppressed", "Activated"), values = c(`FALSE` = 'green', `TRUE` = 'red'))+
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x="Pathway", y="Normalized Enrichment Score",
       title="Curated pathways GSEA") + 
  theme_minimal()
```

Generated output:
[image]

I want to change the label `TRUE` to `Activated` and `DOWN` to `Suppressed`. and `NES > 0` to `regulation` ? How do I do it?

Comment: You are mapping `NES<0` to the `fill` aesthetic. Just change `scale_color_manual` to `scale_fill_manual` with the `name = 'regulation'`. This is probably a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as:

```
ggplot(df, aes(reorder(ID, NES), NES)) +
geom_col(aes(fill=REG)) + 
scale_color_manual(name = 'REG')+
coord_flip() +
  labs(x="Pathway", y="Normalized Enrichment Score",
       title="Curated pathways GSEA") + 
  theme_minimal()
```

Comment: This does not answer OP' s question

Comment: Just exchange `_color_` by `_fill_`.      

`scale_fill_manual(name = "NES",  labels = c("Suppressed", "Activated"),  values = c(`FALSE` = "green", `TRUE` = "red")) 
`